# Check whether a value for search key exists in aanother column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe which contains phone numbers and other column which has the call_status. I want to check if even a single time a phone number is connected then a new column should return True for it else false.

My data is like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMlaR.png)

My output needs to be
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiHWl.png)

Comment: what you have tried. ?

Comment: call_mtd['Checking'] = np.where(call_mtd['Call Status'].str.contains('Contacted'), 'True', 'False')

Comment: bu this is just checking for current value not checking in the entire column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `isin` on `masked` `df`

```
df['Customer Number'].isin(df[df['Call Status']=='Contacted']['Customer Number'])
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Customer Number, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks,brother for the help